# Heroku Bash: ls command not displaying .dat files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, heroku

I am storing some .dat files in the public folder of my rails app on heroku.  However, I cannot display those files in the heroku bash.

Notice the "total 4" in the ls -l result

```
~/public/files $ ls
README.txt

~/public/files $ ls -a
.  ..  README.txt

~/public/files $ ls -l
total 4
-rw------- 1 u5517 5517 25 2013-04-13 23:35 README.txt
```

So I know they are there, they are just not being shown. I need to be able to look at them to verify my app is working correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please post the code for storing the dat file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku dynos have [ephemeral file systems](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem), so if you are writing files in your web process, they will not be available to other dynos, including one created from a `heroku run bash` session. Please also remember that [dynos are restarted at least every 24 hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts), so unless these are just temp files, it would be better to put the file somewhere like S3 that has long-term persistance and can be accessed by all your dynos.

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  Thanks!